# How to make a module in module feature with terraform?

Tags: module, terraform, workflow

For this terraform project structure

```
|- common-modules
|---- development               # Call common-modules/common to use and act as a new module
|-------- main.tf
|-------- variables.tf
|-------- outputs.tf
|---- staging                   # Call common-modules/common to use and act as a new module
|-------- main.tf
|-------- variables.tf
|-------- outputs.tf
|---- production                # Call common-modules/common to use and act as a new module
|-------- main.tf
|-------- variables.tf
|-------- outputs.tf
|---- common                    # Common resources for all the environments
|-------- main.tf
|-------- variables.tf
|-------- outputs.tf
|- development                  # Call common-modules/development to use
|---- main.tf
|---- variables.tf
|---- outputs.tf
|- staging                      # Call common-modules/staging to use
|---- main.tf
|---- variables.tf
|---- outputs.tf
|- production                   # Call common-modules/production to use
|---- main.tf
|---- variables.tf
|---- outputs.tf
```

In `common-modules/common/main.tf`, something like

```
resource "XXX" "example" {
    # hoge
}
```

In `common-modules/development/main.tf`, call `common-modules/common`

```
module "XXX" "YYY" {
    source "../common"
    
    # hoge
}
```

The same as it for `common-modules/staging` and `common-modules/production`.

In `development/main.tf`

```
module "XXX" "ZZZ" {
    source "../common-modules/development"
    
    # hoge
}
```

When run `terraform apply` under `development`, found it executed twice for the contents in `common-modules/common`. Maybe `common-modules/development/main.tf` ran once, then `development/main.tf` ran again.

Then how to make it to run only one time for the resource creatation?

Now using atlantis to run the workflow automatically. In it some setting as

```
version: 3
projects:
  - dir: common-modules/development
    autoplan:
      enabled: true
      when_modified: [ "*.tf" ]

  - dir: development
    autoplan:
      enabled: true
      when_modified: ["*.tf"]
    apply_requirements: [mergeable]
```

Is it possible to avoid auto apply for `common-modules/development` in the first setting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A typical approach for a problem like you described here is [module composition](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/modules/develop/composition.html), where rather than embedding one module inside another one you instead pass data returned from one module (via output values) into the input variables of another module.

This means that your root module will contain all of the `module` blocks, where the results from some will pass into others. I'm not sure how to adapt what you shared in your question into a working example because you didn't show your module output values or input variables, but here is a generic example:

```
module "common" {
  source = "../common-modules/common"
}

module "development" {
  source = "../common-modules/development"

  something = module.common.something
}
```

When you work with these configurations, you should only run Terraform in the `development`, `staging`, and `production` directories and never in any of the `common-modules` directories, because `common-modules` will be used only as part of the root configurations. I'm not really familiar with Atlantis, but I think this means that you should remove `common-modules/development` as a "project" in Atlantis, because it isn't a standalone configuration, just a shared module used as part of the `development` configuration.